# How to send dropzone js values from ajax to mvc controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I need to send the name and dropzone datas to the controller when the button is clicked

this is my code

```
var officePictures = [];

var elem = $(".dz-details").find("img");

    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {

        officePictures.push(elem[i].getAttribute("alt"));

    }

    officePictures = JSON.stringify({ 'officePictures': officePictures });

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Office/AddOffice",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        dataType: "JSON",
        traditional : true, 
        data: {
            OfficeName: $('#Name').val(),
            officePictures : officePictures
        }
    })
```

Actually works correctly but there is a problem in my controller method

[image: Debugger - Dropzone datalist]

As you can see in the picture Dropzone datalist is going but one piece of data is going one by one,how can i solve this problem ???

```
My Controller code 


[HttpPost]
            [ValidateInput(false)]
            public ActionResult AddOffice(string OfficeName,List<string> officePictures)
            {

                Office office = new Office();
                office.OfficeName = OfficeName;
                db.Office.Add(office);
                db.SaveChanges();

                var lastId = db.Office.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().ID;

                foreach (var item in officePictures)
                {
                    OfficePictures ofp = new OfficePictures();
                    ofp.OfficeID = lastId;
                    ofp.PictureURL = item.ToString();
                    ofp.PictureSEO = "aaa";
                    db.OfficePictures.Add(ofp);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("OfficeIndex", "Office");
            }
```

Comment: Show you controller code, not an image of it.

Comment: Remove the following lines of code: `officePictures = JSON.stringify({ 'officePictures': officePictures });` and `enctype: 'multipart/form-data',`

Comment: Try to replace with  enctype: 'multipart/form-data' with  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',